# Python- Error 'adm' not defined

Tags: python

Hi I have the following code below which is giving me a class error.
I do not know what is wrong with the function or class. Please advise. 
Hi I have the following code below which is giving me a class error.
I do not know what is wrong with the function or class. Please adviseHi I have the following code below which is giving me a class error.
I do not know what is wrong with the function or class. Please advise

```
def User(uname):
    print('\nA)post message\nB)see recent post\nc)Quit\n')
    ch=input('enter your choice:')
    if(ch.lower()=='c'):
        return
    elif(ch.lower()=='a'):
        tdmin.UserDict[uname].postMessage()
        user(uname, pswrd)
#define the Admin class
def adminFun(adm):
    print('\nA)add user\nB)remove user\nC)activity of user\nD)display most and least active user\nE)exit\n')
    ch=input('enter your choice:')
    if(ch.lower()=='e'):
        return
    elif(ch.lower()=='a'):
        adm.addUser()
        admin(adm)

class Admin():
    username='admin'
    password='1234'
    userDict = {}
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def addUser(self):
        userDict = {}
        uname = input('Enter a user name:')
        pswrd = input('password:')
        self.userDict[uname] = pswrd
        print(userDict)

if __name__=='__main__':
    while(True):
        print('A)Login\nB)Quit')
        ch=input('Enter your choice:')
        if(ch.lower()=='b'):
            exit()
        elif(ch.lower()=='a'):
            usrname=input('please enter User name:')
            adm = adminFun(adm)
            adm.addUser()
            if(usrname==adm.username):
                passwrd=input('enter {} password:'.format(adm.username))
                if(passwrd==adm.password):
                    admin(adm)
                else:
                    print('incorrect password')
        elif(usrname in adm.UserDict):
            passwrd=input('enter {} password:'.format(usrname))
            if passwrd != adm.UserDict[usrname].pswrd:
                print('password invalid')
            else:
                adm.UserDict[usrname].visit+=1
                user(usrname)

        else:
            print('enter valid username!')



#Dictionary of Users
dict_users = {}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just modify your `no-data` class to include `text-align:center;`?  Would be helpful if you include the css for that class.  Remember, you should provide a minimal set of code so it is reproducible.

Comment: Are you using paging in your grid? If so then the paging bar at the bottom of the grid will have a 'No Items to Display' message.

Comment: @RickS yes, I added the text-align: center and that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ...,
    columns: [...],
    noRecords: {
        template: '<div class="no-data">No data available</div>'
    }
})

.no-data {
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #e2dfda;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: start;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[image: No data]

If you remove float and text-align property it will be centered!

Answer (score 0):

Using the pager on the kendo grid will give you more flexibility on what text you want to display and how you want it aligned.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "column1" },
    { field: "column2" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
  ],
  pageable: {
    pageSize: 2,
    messages: {
      empty: "No matching records found"
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

This way, you can customize the text using css:

```
<style>
    #grid .k-pager-info.k-label {
        float: left
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function gridDataBound(e) {
        var grid = e.sender;
        if (grid.dataSource.total() == 0) {
            var colCount = grid.columns.length;
            $(e.sender.wrapper)
                .find('tbody')
                .append('<tr class="kendo-data-row"><td colspan="' + colCount + '" style="text-align:center; height: 170px; class="no-data">No matching records found</td></tr>');
        }
    };
```